# what exactly are built-in types in Python?

Tags: python

I keep hearing "everything is an object" in both Ruby and Python world. Well, what are built-in functions then? Can someone explain that in layperson English?
For example:

```
file=open(abc.txt)
```

open is a built-in function. Is it an object? Is it a method? Of what class?

How did we even end-up with **functions in Python** if everything is an object? I mean, shouldn't we be having class, objects, methods and attributes, instead of functions? I thought we had functions in languages like C. Python, Ruby and Java had classes, objects, attributes, methods.

In Ruby (**irb**), you could do something like `1.class` and this will give you `Fixnum`it will show you which class it belongs to. I don't seem to be able to do this in Python shell. Is there an equivalent?

FYI:

- I am using Python 2.7
- relatively new to programming so please use layperson English. For instance, I read in one of the answers "But everything is an object in the sense that it can be assigned to a variable or passed as an argument to a function" --- no idea what that means.

Comment: How is "everything is an object" at conflict with having functions?

Comment: @delnan Coming from Java POV, there are no functions. There are methods. And each method belongs to some class. So, if you have a "function" that is an "object". Then that object must belong to some class. And the way to use it would be function.method(). Because you say "function" is an object in Python; I'd think, the way to use "open" would be open.method(). "open" being name of the object and "method" being the method/function. In Java, you can't have a method that doesn't belong to any class/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all listed here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

The function `open` is an object (all functions are objects) and belongs to the `__builtin__` module. They are simply built-in, and available to all objects, since they are automatically imported (something like `from __builtin__ import *`).

```
>>> print repr(open)
<built-in function open>

>>> print open.__module__
__builtin__

>>> import __builtin__
>>> print __builtin__.open
<built-in function open>
```

**Update**
You mentioned in your edit that you don't know what assigning a function means.

```
>>> o = open
>>> print repr(open)
<built-in function open>
>>> print repr(o)
<built-in function open>
>>> o('file.txt')
<open file 'file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x107fe49c0>
```

Comment: So this means __builtin__ is a class? And open is a method of this class?

Comment: It's a module, not a class. And no, it's a function inside a module.

Comment: so, we dont just have classes, attributes, methods and objects. But we also have modules and functions in Python?

Comment: Modules are groups of classes, variables and functions. Classes are groups of methods (with arguments) and variables. Methods are functions that take the class state as the `self` argument. And everything is an object. And all of that must be very confusing if you're new to programming or OO.

Comment: @RedChar Everything in Python is an object, including modules, functions, classes and anything else that you see in the language.

Comment: whoa! I know a bit of Java and this sounds very different from Java. I am going to have to read some book :-) I thought the way it works is, we define classes, attributes, methods. Then we create objects (of those classes) and use methods (of those classes). Like in Java. When you import something in Java, you are simply importing a class. You can create its object and then use methods of those objects.

Comment: While that is a possible workflow in Python as well, it's not something you see a lot. Good luck!

Comment: It *is* very different from Java ;) Python doesn't go the "everything must be object-oriented by being put in a class route". Functions, for instance, are legitimate objects and methods are simply one kind of function associated with a class (and thus, by the way attribute lookup works, with objects of that class).

Comment: ahan! Function is just a piece of code that is called by some name. So, we have builtin functions like open etc. Now, this is what confuses me (I am a bit daft): if "open" just means a block of code, how can "open" be an object? If it is an object, what class does it belong to? Also, if it is an object, how can it do something. I mean, you have to call a method of this object. So, if open is an object. Then we should have a method open.method(filename). Instead of open(filename).

Comment: You're looking at it from the Java POV again... In Python, functions are objects, and functions don't have to belong to a class.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt  yep, from Java POV this seems unfathomable. Functions are objects and objects dont necessarily belong to a class. How can you have an object without having a class. I, so far, have believed that you create a class and then you create objects of that class. It's impossible for an object to exist without having a class for it to belong to.

Comment: But as you may have noticed by now, that's not true. Actually, I suppose you could say that there's a class called Function which holds the name and the memory location of the actual function. Of course it's nothing like that but if it makes it easier for you :-)

Comment: @RedChar: Putting Tom's latest comment the other way around: Functions are objects, and thus instances of some class. Look at `open.__class__` for instance, or define `def f(): pass` and check it's `__class__`. But they aren't necessarily a *method* of some class/objects. A function object has a name, bytecode, argument information, a type/class of which it is an instance, etc. but not a class of which it is a method. Say you define `class C: def f(self): return self`. The function object doesn't even know about `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is an object, but not every object is an instance of a useful class in the classic sense. Some things you're better off treating as plain objects, as far as I can tell (functions are a good example that's already been given).

Note that you can use `type(obj)` or inspect `obj.__class__` to replicate Ruby's `.class` method somewhat (see delnan's comment about the caveat for integers, though). You can also see the 'order' of the full inheritance sequence by issuing `type.mro(type(obj))`.

```
In [7]: type.mro(type(open))
Out[7]: [<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, <type 'object'>]

In [4]: import datetime
In [5]: d = datetime.datetime(2009,11,11)
In [6]: type.mro(type(d))
Out[6]: [<type 'datetime.datetime'>, <type 'datetime.date'>, <type 'object'>]
```

Comment: Note though that `1.__class__` won't work, but only due to syntax. You need `1.0.__class__` or `(1).__class___` to help Python realize it's not a floating point number but attribute access.